How to make differentiated data more smooth in R?
So, I have data, that is cumulative, that is, $x_t=x_{t-1}+x$. I need to get values $x$ of the data. I tried to use function diff(), but it makes the plot of the data very sharp and angular, I would like to smooth the differentiated data, how can I do this?
I tried to usediff() and lag() functions, but diff() function made the data look very angular and unsmooth and lag() function for some reason rendered again cumulative data not differentiated. Each value of the x_t is cumulative sum of all values x_{t-1}, x_{t-2},...,x_{0} + the added value $x$. I need to get the value $x$ of each entry. I am not sure whether $diff()$ is the best solution. I tried to use geom_smooth() as well, but it smoothed the data too much, making the geom_smooth() plot completely different than the original.
This is the segment of the data:
  x           y      z
1   1 397.6828062 group1
2   2 482.9088128 group1
3   3 541.7299032 group1
4   4 704.2077406 group1
5   5 750.6887422 group1
6   6 768.3762029 group1
7   7 676.6482087 group1
8   8 379.2520659 group1
9   9 433.5484571 group1
10 10 364.4439592 group1
11 11 247.2131145 group1
12 12 124.6348980 group1
13 13  36.1975941 group1
14 14   0.4113363 group1
15 15   0.0000000 group1
16 16   0.0000000 group1
17 17   0.0000000 group1
18 18   0.0000000 group1
19 19   0.0000000 group1
20 20   0.0000000 group1

This is the plot:

I got the data by using function diff() on the original data.

I think it would be more beneficial if you provided a sample of the data rather than explaining its origin.

@missuse I added a fragmented data and the plot.

If the formula for your data-generating process is correct, diff gives you x. It is unclear why you need smoothing. Should your formula perhaps include a random noise term?

Numerical differentiation is noisy and unstable by amplifying high frequency noise. You can only realistically hope to get a decent estimate if the function that you try to differentiate is noise free (even then it isn't easy to get good answers). Given your sparse noisy dataset the symmetric difference is about as good as it gets ie. dy/dx = (x[t+1]-x[t-1]/2 in this case. Much better experimental technique to measure  directly rather than cumulative if at all possible. Your data is confusing - you have called t x and duplicated it twice and column z seems to contain the cumulative stuff.

You could use a differential filter, with the signal package:
library(signal) 

# Same as diff
n <- 1
diff1 <- filter(Arma(b=c(rep(1,n),rep(-1,n))/n^2,a=1),y)

# Increase smoothing
n <- 3
diffn <- filter(Arma(b=c(rep(1,n),rep(-1,n))/n^2,a=1),y,)[round(n/2):length(y)]
plot(diff1)
lines(diffn,col=2)


Data
data <- read.table(text='
x           y      z
1   1 397.6828062 group1
2   2 482.9088128 group1
3   3 541.7299032 group1
4   4 704.2077406 group1
5   5 750.6887422 group1
6   6 768.3762029 group1
7   7 676.6482087 group1
8   8 379.2520659 group1
9   9 433.5484571 group1
10 10 364.4439592 group1
11 11 247.2131145 group1
12 12 124.6348980 group1
13 13  36.1975941 group1
14 14   0.4113363 group1
15 15   0.0000000 group1
16 16   0.0000000 group1
17 17   0.0000000 group1
18 18   0.0000000 group1
19 19   0.0000000 group1
20 20   0.0000000 group1',header=T)

y <- cumsum(data$y)


Assuming that the question is how to smooth the numeric data shown in the question, we can use a kernel smoother as shown.  The black line in the graph is the original data shown in the question (and also the Note at the end) and the red line is the smoothed data. The smoothness can be varied by adjusting the bandwidth= value.
plot(y ~ x, DF, type = "l")
ks <- with(DF, ksmooth(x, y, "normal", bandwidth = 1.5))
lines(ks, col = "red")

(continued after graph)

or using ggplot2 with ks from above:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(ks), col = "red")

Note
DF <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20,
  y = c(
    397.6828062, 482.9088128, 541.7299032, 704.2077406, 750.6887422, 768.3762029,
    676.6482087, 379.2520659, 433.5484571, 364.4439592, 247.2131145, 124.634898,
    36.1975941, 0.4113363, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  ),
  z = rep("group1", 20L))

